# how to change the magento theme structure of my second store

Tags: multistore

i made a second website in my main magento store by using sub directory. it is ok and running.But i want to show extra template for that. where to edit and put..

And what is my directory structure of my second store?

Comment: my second website is dollar based with multi language option, i am just created like in magento root directory i put internation. like                                   abc.com/international/. Is their any phtmlfile or locale file needed for this

Answer (score 1):

You don't need subfolders for Magento multisite. Everything can be done under one Magento installation with no subfolders.

See this article: https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains

Let me know exactly the structure you want to have and I will advise you in detail.

Comment: I have using multi-store, how can i change header and footer for my second store, and i am using the same theme for both stores, how can i change header and footer for my scend store.

Answer (score 0):

visit this link it will gives full discription.

you have to set `app > design > frontend > > package1 > theme1`

second store `app > design > frontend > package2 > theme2`

visit above link will give you complete description about setup front as well as backend.

**I hope this will help you.**